# node.js Express/socket.io hybrid application with facebook

Tags: session, node.js, express, socket.io

I am using express/socket.io combination in my node.js app. So far it's working fine.
Now, I need to store **facebook user id and email id** (after user being authorized) into session scope. I see there are lot of options and a bit lost here.. in my app, most of the communications happen through socket.io.. ultimately what i want is to access user id and email id anytime in the client side...

```
var express = require("express"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    app = express.createServer(
        form({ keepExtensions: true })
    ),
    io = require("socket.io");

socket = io.listen(app);
```

Answer (score 1):

After being authorized, I suggest using the accessToken which is already in the cookies and then sending it through the socket.io and fetching the email and the id using graph.facebook or your own DB. The problem with storing user ID and Email is that it could insecure, since session hijacking could happen.

Facebook has its own experts on security to make sure it wouldn't be hijacked. Use it!

Comment: This is exactly what i am doing.. problem was how to store it in the session scope. Probably Cris-O's info will help. Thanks for your last comment, "Facebook has its own experts on security to make sure it wouldn't be hijacked. Use it!"

Comment: Actually if you use the javascript SKD of Facebook, the accessToken would be already stored in the cookies. So no worries about that.
You can also use [everyauth module](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) which takes care of all the authentication. And you can even use it with other systems, such as tweeter, google or Yahoo. And it is quite mature.

Comment: Thanks. For the time being my problem is solved by using simple cookie. Will use everyauth in future if required.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

http://criso.github.com/fbgraph/

After being authorized you can store the data in your session via express

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#session-support

On a very basic level:

```
// Get data from facebok and store it on a var `userData`

// server
socket.on('getUserData', function (callback) {
    callback(facebookUserData);
});



// client
socekt.emit('getUserData', function(userData) {
    console.log(userData);      
});
```

Comment: I have seen http://criso.github.com/fbgraph. How is it different from facebook-js ? Currently I am using it and able to read and post using graph api.. But I found YQL to be even better than these. You do not have to understand how facebook/twitter/etc works internally.. Anyway my problem is simple. How can I store userID in session scope ? Mostly I'm using socket.io... in "http://socket.io/#how-to-use", they have given an example, but not sure how to use it. mainly I want to be able to access userId as and when required from the client side.

Comment: I've added to the above answer, since code here looks like crap

Comment: beautiful. thanks much. If I have understood this correctly, 1. from client side you send "getUserData", on server side upon receiving "getUserData", execute a callback with facebook user data, that finally executes "function(userData)"... well will try this tomorrow and will update my observation.

Comment: I have used cookie to solve my problem and it's working fine. Here is the link of the cookie plugin i used. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie